# Many insertion into a big string

Tags: javascript, string, performance, memory, insert

I have a string 200 000 symbols wide. I need to replace `\index{term1}` with `\index0001{term1}`, `\index{term2}` with `\index0002{term2}` etc. So, for every term i have an index number which i need to insert right after `\index`. If specific term met more than one, then its index number still the same.

Number of such replacement is known beforehand. I also know exact position for every replacement.

How can I do it fast?

I'm newbee in JS, in С++ i would allocate buffer big enough for new string and copy parts between replacements, and insert replacements in between.

Comment: We would like to see Effort and Code in a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan I more like need an idea, i can google for code or write it myself pretty easily. Performance matters.

Comment: Such questions are off topic at SO. How about split and join? I would like to see a before and after example with better example terms

Comment: @mplungjan i can't split, because i don't have single separator. Parts inside curly braces may vary significantly.

Comment: So have a look to see how  long it takes to loop/replace - `for (var i=0;i<terms.length;i++) longstring=longstring.replace(new Regex("index"+term[i],"/g"),"\index"+pad(i)+term[i])`

Comment: @mplungjan thanks, i will get back with my code and measurements

Comment: have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this

```js
function pad(num){
  return ("0000"+num).slice(-4);
}
var longstring = "\indexterm1, \indexterm3, \indexterm3",
 terms = ["term1","term2","term3"],
  parts = longstring.split("index");

for (var i=1;i<parts.length;i++) { // start at 1 since \index splits weird
  var part = parts[i].split(",")[0],
      pos = terms.indexOf(part);
  parts[i]="\\index"+pad(pos+1)+part+", ";
}
longstring=parts.join("");

console.log(longstring);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could separate the number and pad it and return it with the matched string.

```js
var string = '\index{term1}\index{term2}\index{term95}',
    result = string.replace(/\{term(\d+)\}/g, function (match, n) {
        n = n.toString();
        while (n.length < 4) {
            n = '0' + n;
        }
        return n + match;
    });

console.log(result);
```